# mysqli_connect() gives: Warning: mysqli_connect(): in C:\wamp\www\kolmas\config\setup.php on line 16

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code on lines 15-16-17:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','developer','password1','kolmas');
?>
```

This line is placed to setup.php file, which is included to index.php file (at the top of document, line 1)

```
<?php include('config/setup.php'); ?>
```

Database is located at wampserver, username, password and database name are checked 20 times. Wamp server is "server Online". When I load the index.php page, it show the page, css and all, but on top of everything there´s a Warning:

http://www.5toneface.eu/temp/index.html

What may be the cause and solution?

Comment: Is `mysqli` enabled?

Comment: if it wasn't enabled it would throw a fatal error. do `echo mysqli_connect_error();` which will tell you why it failed.

Comment: That's an odd warning, there's no actual message

Comment: Maybe the error handler is messed up for some reason? Try a custom error handler like exception_error_handler / http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

Comment: Check whether this happens same with **mysql_connect($servername, $username_db, $password_db);**

Answer (score 0):

use this type connection to connect database :-

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'developer', 'password1');


if (!$mysqli) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else{ 
    $mysqli->select_db("kolmas");
}
```

Comment: I tried that, put result to same url http://www.5toneface.eu/temp/index.html

pic no 2

Comment: I also added images of my code files setup.php and index.php to this url

http://www.5toneface.eu/temp/index.html

Comment: Problem has to be with mysql. When I connect with "root" and no password, everything works. 
  But when I create new user, for instance "dev" and put password something like "password1" - and put them as parameters - then I get this warning - it acts as if the password were wrong or something. 

When i put to parameters root - and try to connect with wrong password, inserting for example no 4 as a password - i get pretty similar warning but without any content of the page and with this text under warning: ConnectionError: Accčs refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)

Comment: The content goes away though because i used OR die() function. But problem with other users than ROOT still remains @Phil